# Next arguments of function definition depending on first argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, overloading

Consider a list of simple functions with different arguments:

```
const fns = {
  isValidDate: (input: string, min?: Date, max?: Date): boolean => {
     // ...
     return true;
  },

  isValidOption: (input: string, options: string[]): boolean => {
     // ...
     return true;
  },

};
```

They all return the same type (bool);

Then another function that is supposed to call any of the functions above:

```
function validateField(where: string, fn: keyof typeof fns, ...args: any[]){
   // ...
   return fns[fn](...args);
}
```

How can I make `args` reflect the parameters of the chose `fn` ?

For example:

```
validateField("test", "isValidDate", new Date()); // should be ok 
validateField("test", "isValidDate", 123); // should fail
```

and have the arguments show in vscode hints, like on normal functions.

I know I need to create overloads for `validateField` for each `fn`, but how to do that with a type definitions or something... without having to manually define each overload and write duplicate code with those arguments

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mq3Gjw) meet your needs?  The underlying issue is lack of direct support for *correlated unions* as requested in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended solution is type refactoring using generics as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  If this fully addresses your question then I can write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing? (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: as a side note, this would be much easier with OOP rather than functions: e.g `class DateValidator implements Validator`, `class OptionValidator...` etc and then simply `validate(input, validators: Validator[])`.

Comment: @jcalz it does seem to work as expected! you should post it as answer :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want `validateField()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the `fn` parameter so you can choose the appropriate type for `args`.  We can write some helper utility types to compute this:

```
type Fns = typeof fns;

type FnArgs = { [K in keyof Fns]: 
  Fns[K] extends (input: string, ...args: infer A) => boolean ? A : never 
};

/* type FnArgs = {
    isValidDate: [min?: Date | undefined, max?: Date | undefined];
    isValidOption: [options: string[]];
} */
```

The `FnArgs` type is a [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) type where each key comes from the type of `fns`, and each value is the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of parameters after the initial `string` (using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to get that list).

Now you can give `validateField()` this call signature:

```
declare function validateField<K extends keyof Fns>(
  where: string, fn: K, ...args: FnArgs[K]
): boolean;
```

and it will work when you call it:

```
validateField("test", "isValidDate", new Date()); //  okay
validateField("test", "isValidDate", 123); // error! number is not assignable to date
validateField("test", "isValidOption", ["a"]) // okay
```

---

Unfortunately the implementation of `validateField()` does not type check:

```
function validateField<K extends keyof Fns>(where: string, fn: K, ...args: FnArgs[K]) {
  return fns[fn](where, ...args); // error!  
  // -----------------> ~~~~~~~
  // A spread argument must either have a tuple type or 
  // be passed to a rest parameter.
}
```

The underlying issue is lack of direct support for *correlated unions* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  The compiler is not able to understand that the type of `fns[fn]` is of a function type that is correlated with the type of `args`.  The error message is a bit cryptic, but it comes from the fact that it sees `args` as a union of tuple types inappropriate for the arguments of `fns[fn]`, which it sees as a union of function types without a common rest parameter type.

Luckily there's a recommended solution for this described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  We need to give `fns` a new type that the compiler can see at a glance is an object with methods whose parameters are directly related to `FnArgs`.  Here's how it looks:

```
function validateField<K extends keyof Fns>(where: string, fn: K, ...args: FnArgs[K]) {
  const _fns: { [K in keyof Fns]: (str: string, ...args: FnArgs[K]) => boolean } = fns;
  return _fns[fn](where, ...args); // okay
}
```

The `_fns` variable is [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) as being of a mapped type of methods explicitly with a rest parameter of tpe `FnArgs[K]` for every `K` in the keys of `Fns`.  The assignment of `fns` to that variable succeeds, because it's the same type.

But the crucial difference is that `_fns[fn](where, ...args)` succeeds where `fns[fn](where, ...args)` fails.  And that's because the compiler has kept track of the correlation across the generic `K` between the type of `_fns[fn]` and the type of `args`.

And now you have something that works as desired for both the callers and the implementation of the function!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.8.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZpGBeGBvAUDGBLCA1AQwBtsATAEQKgFMAuGACmzAAcBXKe6AJ2YHMANDAC2zAPz1KNIcIIAPCTCnUAlPQBGIEEWoEwyAHxpMWGAHozMAHQ2TWbtShtu+qNzbUA3CYC+A9Ca4hCSkAPIsUNjg9EysHFxu-EIgEVGQCbxgfADaALpqMJrauvpIRhim5pY2VnYwDk4uMG4e3lh+6D7e6FAAnizUMABiiCh9AyBw8JDe44MjAILcfBDIaDDZANI4+gDW1L2Tw5C59CMQW7kw1HI0YKSrseycMDxJ1jYEyxD0zHDU3BgCxUhkKWh0ehgYiBMHoYGoADcATAugEzAAqZr9eZgJYrNYVUxBYhkZT0bKiMCKZQwAA+MDY92ocGY1FIMnk1Kog3pjNIzNZpFybSJ+BJYVS0Q2KUi4B+r0SWTyws6MHRZgCcEZwFl+gR4u5Q2w1CIpAAQtwQPswABJYQsIgAHm2NzuDxg+0OU3OBgYAHcABYAugKzKCab0TZCGpfFZnXHfS4gwkNZz6BAXBC5f1BhzRz7fFSeKrXbiW7gAQiwJgsMAAtA3G03mw2jAA-Dudts1ywLV4sBwEUgwWNsYTUMCwYRsaDXbBQXMwAMEJEj5psB2DOYwECAnuFQYsAgQCBs5ogNcOWdH7gEcc0bi1HwBfUhQ3G00MABENGgX6EX7EiEyj-jA8J+ko3IMCoRYljuuwEL06CvmQ74mqQ36-lAoGAWKwHcqBACMABMADMsG1gC5ZVmAY7qMiuBgSAsDHhA2B8GABDqDo54wKQ3LIQaNBGuhmHUH+AFAWQ4S6qB2RfgQX75CWVqIZq2q6jAKH8cJH6kM61y3BO7qekcPo5sGGTvAgkb5lYsbyosiabMphKgJAsAAPoZvQqAbNszAegcZknDEPBWVkdkOfGeIXC5IJlGCxSQj4awZiKqZNN5kDZFmFl5h89mFsWtaqUhz4BEAA)

Answer (score 0):

To solve your question, you can use the Generic type to get the function type and then use this to get the type of the parameter

```js
function validateField<key extends keyof typeof fns>(where: string, fn: key, ...options: Parameters<typeof fns[key]>): boolean {
  const fnToCall = fns[fn];
  return fnToCall(...options);
}
```

Comment: Note that your code as written has a compiler error at `..options` inside `fnToCall(...options)`.